# how to update spyder on anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I have Anaconda installed (Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32)  and I am using Spyder 2.3.8

Would like to update Spyder to the latest version, so I went through the commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update spyder
```

They all ran without errors, but the spyder version didn't change - this is command I'm using to launch:

> C:\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda2\cwp.py C:\Anaconda2 "C:/Anaconda2/pythonw.exe" "C:/Anaconda2/Scripts/spyder-script.py" --new-instance

Am I missing something?

Comment: why not `conda update spyder`?

Comment: `conda update spyder` worked just fine for me

Comment: @GeorgeKis convert your comment to an answer!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548373/how-to-update-spyder/52783385#52783385) updates Spyder inside Anaconda's platform with few clicks.

Comment: @boardtc I can't convert my comment to an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeKis convert as in add an answer with these details as it's the proper answer!

Comment: Something is confusing here. The question states that "conda update spyder" has been tried out unsuccessfully, yet the asker himself agrees with the solution to try out "conda update spyder" here in the comments. Has there been a weird edit that changed the question?

Comment: ```conda update spyder``` did not work for me, but the answer by @notilas did.

Comment: you can force update to specific version using conda install spyder=5.2

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To expand on [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga)'s comment:

If you want to update Spyder in the root environment, then `conda update spyder`
works for me.

If you want to update Spyder for a virtual environment you have created (e.g., for a different version of Python), then `conda update -n $ENV_NAME spyder` where `$ENV_NAME` is your environment name.

EDIT: In case `conda update spyder` isn't working, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265097/trouble-updating-to-spyder-4-0-0) indicates you might need to run `conda update anaconda` before updating spyder. Also note that you can specify an exact spyder version if you want.

Comment: to update Spyder for VE, one can open a terminal from the VE and then use `conda update spyder` ... this has worked form me

Comment: Yes, that will also work. That's equivalent to opening a normal terminal, activating the environment, and then entering `conda update spyder`.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. I executed ```conda update spyder```, and it updated several packages, but spyder stayed at 4.1.3. Then I tried ```conda update spyder``` again, and got the message ```# All requested packages already installed.```, but spyder was still at 4.1.3. Finally, I tried the answer by @notilas, which worked to update spyder to 4.1.4.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Hard for me to say exactly what didn't work without recreating your environment. My best guess is an existing issue where anaconda has to be updated before spyder, so I added an edit about that. But glad you got something to work.

Comment: And in my case, nothing found here helped. I tried to see whether the newer version is available in Anaconda Navigator, but it was not. I then elected to upgrading the Jupyter Notebook that had an upgrade available and suddenly the Anaconda Navigator offered to upgrade itself, which I did, and then Spyder and many more apps became available to me with newer versions, too. What an odd application management on the Anaconda part!

Comment: I wonder... is there a way to update ```spyder``` in all environments through terminal, without needing to activate each environment?

Answer (score 24):

Go to Anaconda Naviagator, find spyder,click settings in the top right corner of the spyder app.click update [tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95rtn.png)

Comment: would this work if admin privileges are required and you don't have credentials?

Comment: Would likely work if Anaconda is not that buggy.

Comment: FYI: This does not work unless anaconda has put out the update.  Right now, Anaconda is a few versions behind Spyder's version.  And it will not let you update to the latest until Anaconda releases it.

Answer (score 22):

I see that you used pip to update. This is strongly discouraged (at least in Spyder 3). The Spyder update notices I receive have always included the following:

"IMPORTANT NOTE: It seems that you are using Spyder with Anaconda/Minconda. Please don't use pip to update it as that will probably break your installation. Instead please wait until new conda packages are available and use conda to perform the update."

Answer (score 20):

Use this `conda install spyder=4.0.0`
This will not mess up your anaconda dependencies.
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases

Comment: I tried your method, but I get the following message: Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Comment: This answer is what worked for me to update from spyder 4.1.3 to 4.1.4. I got the same message as @henry, followed by another: ```Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.```, then finally ```Solving environment: done``` After entering "y" to ```Proceed ([y]/n)?``` it updated.

Answer (score 10):

Simply select 'Update Application' after clicking on the settings symbol(top right corner) for Spyder in the Anaconda Navigator console. In my case I just updated it so it's in disabled state.

[image]

Comment: Note that this only works if Anaconda is up to date itself. If Anaconda is not up to date (which it will not tell you), then the button will be greyed out. I was in that situation right now, I was trying to update Spyder but it would not let me, and did not tell me why. Once Anaconda was updated, there suddenly was an indication that a new Spyder version was out and could be installed.

Answer (score 8):

use this command

```
conda install spyder=5.0.1
```

this will install the new version or tell you the error

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
> current channels

How to solve the error 
**1- update your anaconda**

```
conda update anaconda
```

2- go to anaconda then spyder

[image]

or  use this command

```
conda install spyder=5.0.0
```

Comment: Not working for me. I getPackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - spyder=5.0.1

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

Comment: So you need to specifically tell conda to look in, say, conda-forge

Comment: How long should this take please? I find if I use the Navigator->Spyder->Install Specific Versin method, it just sits there with a message saying it's updating forever.

Comment: This helped me: `conda config --add channels conda-forge` then I could install the latest version. I also then launched Spyder from the terminal `spyder` rather than in the apps launcher (not sure if the app link updates or not)

Answer (score 6):

make sure you in your base directory.
then `conda install spyder` will work.
Do it like this: `conda install spyder=new_version_number`.
**new_version_number** should be in digits.

Answer (score 4):

One way to avoid errors during installing or updating packages is to run the Anaconda prompt as Administrator. Hope it helps!

Comment: You should ALWAYS run Anaconda Navigator as Administrator, and make sure it is installed with System Administrator privileges.  Otherwise many package updates and creating virtual environments can fail.  Package installations and updates that use pip and need to compile source code into an executable or DLL will fail.  As a developer, lack of full administrator privileges has caused more install and configuration failures for me than any other issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily install update version if you use Anaconda by closing Spyder and then running the following command in a system terminal (Anaconda Prompt on Windows, xterm on Linux or Terminal.app on macOS):

```
conda install spyder= Your desire version
```

(For example, Version is  3.1)

```
conda install spyder=3.1
```

Or you can use pip with this command in a system terminal (cmd.exe on Windows, xterm on Linux or Terminal.app on macOS):

```
pip install --pre -U spyder
```

Note: Do not use this command if you are using Anaconda because it could break your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Using pip directly:

WARNING: This will break your Anaconda Installation as described by Spyder maintainer in the comments below; you can try this solution only if the solution mentioned above that use Conda do not work

> pip install --upgrade spyder

You might get an error once launching the new Spyder "nbconvert >= 4.0: None (NOK)", which will require you to resinstall configparser:

> conda uninstall configparser
>
> conda install configparser

You should now have a fresh and up to date installation of Spyder.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This answer is incorrect because the OP is asking about how to update Spyder *in* Anaconda. Using `pip` will certainly break your Anaconda installation because it pulls `pyqt5`, which is binary incompatible with the `pyqt` conda package. So, could you remove this answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hello Carlos, Thanks for the input. I have added a Warning in my answer. I do not want to delete the answer because even tough you mention it will break the installation, it ended up working out for me whereas the other solution did not solve my problem, so it could help others. If you think I should modify something later on to make the solution better let me know and I'd be happy to do so. Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

In iOS,

- Open Anaconda Navigator
- Launch Spyder
- Click on the tab "Consoles" (menu bar)
- Then, "New Console"
- Finally, in the console window, type `conda update spyder`

Your computer is going to start downloading and installing the new version. After finishing, just restart Spyder and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy just in 2 click

1. Open Anaconda Navigator
2. Go to Spyder icon
3. Click on settings logo top-right coner     of spider box
4. Click update application

That it
Happy coding

Comment: I <3 this answer, but it didn't work. When I open Spyder it says v5.4.3 is available. Navigator says I have v5.0.5 installed but the 'update' link is grayed out. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was uninstalla spyder and installa again.
Solved my problem:

```
conda uninstall spyder
conda install spyder=5
```