# How to update Spyder?

Tags: anaconda, spyder, updating

Everytime I start Spyder (with Anaconda) I get a message saying that my version is outdated and I should update it, so I followed the instructions Spyder's own website gave me, which is running the following commands:

```
conda update qt pyqt
conda update spyder
```

But Spyder tells me that syntax is invalid.
What should I do?

Comment: Are you running virtual environments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update spyder on anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849718/how-to-update-spyder-on-anaconda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Those commands are not meant to be run inside Spyder consoles, but in a system terminal (`cmd.exe` on Windows, `xterm` on Linux or `Terminal.app` on macOS). And please don't forget to close Spyder before doing that.

I updated the text in our Releases page to make that crystal clear.

Comment: Thank you!
But when I try and do that, that's what happens:

C:\Users\Usuario>conda update qt pyqt conda update spyder

PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: D:\Arquivos de Programas\Anaconda2
  package name: update



C:\Users\Usuario>

Comment: Those are two different commands, that's why they are shown in two lines instead of one. So you need to write first `conda update qt pyqt`, press enter, wait until that command finishes and then write `conda update spyder` and press enter.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I know you're the system maintainer so let me ask a similar question. I'm running in virtual environments for python 3.6 and 2.7.13. I recently update Spyder by running 'conda upgrade spyder'.  it seemed to work. Will I run into problem not using the 'conda update qt pyqt' command?

Comment: @jmh, no, don't worry about it. Updating qt and pyqt is just a safety measure to be sure that you're using the latest graphical libraries needed by Spyder.

Answer (score 10):

From Anaconda home locate the gear in Spyder's frame and press "Update application". [image]

Comment: My “update application” is grayed out, even though I’m on Spyder 3.3.6, and Spyder 4.0.0 is available. How do I update to the new version?

Answer (score 3):

You need to run those commands on a console with administrative rights, in windows, or with a `sudo` before them on linux.

I tend to run these three lines in order every time I need to update:

```
conda update conda -y
conda update --all -y
conda update qt pyqt spyder -y
```

In Windows I put those three lines in the end of a .bat file (just create a new .txt and then change it's format), right after [the code to make sure it has administrative rights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10052222/3026320).

Updating qt, pyqt and spyder last means sometimes one of those three will rollback an update made to one or more of their dependencies, but in doing so it ensures that in the end spyder will run.