# Trouble updating to Spyder 4.0.0

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

I am under Windows 10, 64 bits.

I tried several time to update Spyder 4.0.0 with both the Anaconda Prompt and the Anaconda Navigator.
It failed. I uninstalled Anaconda and reinstalled it.

Then I ran the Anaconda Prompt as an Administrator and executed :

```
conda update spyder
```

The version of Spyder was 3.3.6.
I tried this command :

```
conda install spyder=4.0.0
```

The prompt returned :

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Finding conflicts:   0%|                                                                       | 0/360 [00:00<?, ?it/s]|Examining hpack:  42%|█████████████████████████▌                                   | 151/360 [00:00<00:00, 1468.80it/s]/Examining jupyter_core:  56%|██████████████████████████████▍                       | 203/360 [00:00<00:00, 1468.80it/-
- mparing specs that have this dependency:   0%|                                                | 0/20 [00:00<?, ?it/\
Examining jupyter_core:  57%|██████████████████████████████▌                       | 204/360 [00:20<00:00, 1468.80it/s]|| mparing specs that have this dependency:  10%|████                                    | 2/20 [00:18<02:47,  9.32s/i/ |
Comparing specs that have this dependency:  55%|█████████████████████▍                 | 11/20 [01:07<00:55,  6.16s/i-
Examining tbb:  73%|███████████████████████████████████████████████▎                 | 262/360 [02:35<01:19,  1.24it/s]-Examining jedi:  81%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████▉            | 292/360 [02:35<00:54,  1.24it/- \
Examining jupyter_client:  90%|████████████████████████████████████████████████▍     | 323/360 [06:03<04:23,  7.12s/i\ \
Comparing specs that have this dependency:   7%|██▋                                     | 1/15 [00:10<02:27, 10.51s/i-
Comparing specs that have this dependency:  13%|█████▎                                  | 2/15 [00:21<02:19, 10.73s/i/ |
Comparing specs that have this dependency:  27%|██████████▋                             | 4/15 [00:31<01:25,  7.77s/i\ \
Finding conflict paths:   0%|                                                                    | 0/7 [00:00<?, ?it// -
Comparing specs that have this dependency:  73%|████████████████████████████▌          | 11/15 [01:21<00:29,  7.40s/i\ |
Finding shortest conflict path for jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']:  67%|██████████▋     | 4/6 [00:10<00:01,  1.35it/| -
Comparing specs that have this dependency:  80%|███████████████████████████████▏       | 12/15 [01:34<00:23,  7.91s/i- |
failed                                                                                                                 /
                                                                                                                       \
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with a past
explicit spec that is not an explicit spec in this operation (spyder):

  - spyder=4.0.0

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package jedi conflicts for:
spyder=4.0.0 -> python-language-server[version='>=0.31.2,<0.32.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.14.1,<0.16']
jedi
jupyterlab_server -> notebook -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
anaconda==2019.10 -> jedi==0.15.1[build='py37_0|py36_0|py27_0']
ipython -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
qtconsole -> ipykernel[version='>=4.1'] -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf -> ipywidgets -> ipython[version='>=4.0.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
jupyter_console -> ipython -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
spyder-kernels -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
widgetsnbextension -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
jupyter -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
spyder=4.0.0 -> qtconsole[version='>=4.6.0'] -> ipykernel[version='>=4.1'] -> ipython[version='>=5.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
ipywidgets -> ipython[version='>=4.0.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
notebook -> ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
ipykernel -> ipython[version='>=4.0'] -> jedi[version='>=0.10']
anaconda==2019.10 -> spyder==3.3.6=py27_0 -> jedi[version='>=0.10|>=0.9']
spyder=4.0.0 -> jedi=0.14.1
Package jupyter_client conflicts for:
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf -> jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
widgetsnbextension -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
ipywidgets -> widgetsnbextension[version='>=3.3.0,<3.4.0'] -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1|>=5.3.4']
jupyterlab_server -> notebook -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1|>=5.3.4']
anaconda==2019.10 -> ipykernel==4.10.0=py27_0 -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.1|>=5.2.0|>=5.2.3|>=5.3.1']
jupyter -> ipykernel -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.1|>=4.2|>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1|>=5.3.4']
ipywidgets -> widgetsnbextension[version='>=3.3.0,<3.4.0'] -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
spyder=4.0.0 -> qtconsole[version='>=4.6.0'] -> ipykernel[version='>=4.1'] -> jupyter_client
jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1|>=5.3.4']
spyder=4.0.0 -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.1|>=4.2|>=5.3.4']
ipywidgets -> ipykernel[version='>=4.5.1'] -> jupyter_client
anaconda==2019.10 -> jupyter_client==5.3.3[build='py27_1|py36_1|py37_1']
spyder-kernels -> ipykernel -> jupyter_client
jupyter_console -> jupyter_client
spyder-kernels -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.3|>=5.3.4']
notebook -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
jupyter_client
notebook -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1|>=5.3.4']
nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf -> ipywidgets -> ipykernel[version='>=4.5.1'] -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1|>=5.3.4']
jupyterlab_server -> notebook -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2']
widgetsnbextension -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.0|>=5.3.1|>=5.3.4']
ipykernel -> jupyter_client
qtconsole -> ipykernel[version='>=4.1'] -> jupyter_client
qtconsole -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.1']
Package jupyter_core conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.10 -> jupyter_core==4.5.0=py_0
spyder=4.0.0 -> nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2'] -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.6.0']
nbconvert -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.2'] -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.6.0']
jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0|>=4.6.0']
ipywidgets -> ipykernel[version='>=4.5.1'] -> jupyter_client -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0|>=4.6.0']
anaconda-project -> anaconda-client -> nbformat[version='>=4.4.0'] -> jupyter_core
jupyter_core
anaconda-navigator -> anaconda-client[version='>=1.6'] -> nbformat[version='>=4.4.0'] -> jupyter_core
jupyter -> notebook -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0|>=4.6.0']
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf -> jupyterlab -> notebook[version='>=4.3.1'] -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0|>=4.6.0']
spyder-kernels -> jupyter_client[version='>=5.2.3'] -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.6.0']
widgetsnbextension -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0|>=4.6.0']
notebook -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0|>=4.6.0']
ipywidgets -> nbformat[version='>=4.2.0'] -> jupyter_core
anaconda-client -> nbformat[version='>=4.4.0'] -> jupyter_core
nbformat -> jupyter_core
jupyter_console -> jupyter_client -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.6.0']
anaconda==2019.10 -> jupyter_client==5.3.3=py27_1 -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0']
qtconsole -> jupyter_core
ipykernel -> jupyter_client -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.6.0']
spyder=4.0.0 -> nbconvert -> jupyter_core
jupyter_client -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.6.0']
nbconvert -> jupyter_core
jupyterlab_server -> notebook -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.4.0|>=4.6.0']
qtconsole -> jupyter_client[version='>=4.1'] -> jupyter_core[version='>=4.6.0']
Package spyder-kernels conflicts for:
spyder=4.0.0 -> spyder-kernels[version='>=1.8.1,<2.0.0']
spyder-kernels
anaconda==2019.10 -> spyder-kernels==0.5.2[build='py37_0|py36_0|py27_0']
anaconda==2019.10 -> spyder==3.3.6=py27_0 -> spyder-kernels[version='>=0.5.0,<1']
Package qtconsole conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.10 -> qtconsole==4.5.5=py_0
jupyter -> qtconsole
anaconda==2019.10 -> jupyter==1.0.0=py27_7 -> qtconsole[version='>=4.2']
spyder=4.0.0 -> qtconsole[version='>=4.6.0']
qtconsole
```

When launching the Anaconda Navigator, the Spyder version was still on 3.3.6.

What am I missing to benefit the last version of Spyder ?

**EDIT 1:**

When I try to use the Anaconda Navigator, it says :

> spyder 4.0.0 cannot be installed on this environment

And it proposes other environments to install but I want Spyder to be updated, not installed somewhere else.

**EDIT 2:**
I successfuly change conda to 4.6, but I get these two errors :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Menu\\spyder_shortcut.jsodone
```

and :

```
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe 
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
```

The `conda clean --packages` command does not help since the same errors are raised after it is executed.

Comment: Try using  conda install -c anaconda spyder

Comment: @obiwankenobi it returned the same version of Spyder (3.3.6)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Other users have reported that you need to run

`conda update anaconda`

and then

`conda install spyder=4`

to successfully update to version 4.

Comment: What does this mean ? ```Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.```

Comment: Those are just warning messages. Don't pay attention to them.

Comment: it did not work, the comands ran successfuly but Spyder is not 4

Comment: I had the same issue. I re-installed conda and was able to update Spyder to v4.0.0. My problem is that as soon as Spyder starts up in an environment with Python 2.7 it crashes immediately; however, it works fine with Python 3.x

Comment: This is my error : `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\brichard\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Menu\\spyder_shortcut.jsodone`

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thank You @CarlosCordoba

Comment: for me...after the command line update, I had to go back to the Anaconda Navigator to update the app (click on wheel sign in the Spyder app box)

Comment: Some how this process kept installing 3.6 even after deleting manyally the spyder executable. From anaconda navigator I couldn't get any version above 3.6. THis is what worked:
1) from the navigator, uninstall spyder
2) install spyder
it magically pulled 4.0.1

Comment: Also did it for me in the Anaconda Prompt **with administrator privileges**. Awesome!

Comment: @andy removing spyder from the navigator worked. Then the suggested spyder version was 4.0.1, weird magic.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I can't install Spyder 4.1.2 from the anaconda navigator (says it's available). It just hangs for every saying that it's "upgrading". Can you comment on this?

Comment: You can't update from navigator. You need to use the Anaconda Prompt and run the commands I wrote in my answer above.

Answer (score 8):

I used the following:

```
conda update anaconda
```

and then

```
conda update spyder
conda install spyder=4.0.1
```

to successfully update to version 4.0.1

Comment: this what I expect to be behind the GUI update button

Answer (score 5):

An additional note here for those trying to upgrade to Spyder 4 and use conda environments in Windows 10. I was wanting to use Spyder 4 but also getting the error inside Spyder saying that it could not find the spyder-kernels. This happened regardless of (1) whether or not I installed Spyder inside a new environment or the base environment, and (2) even if I subsequently installed spyder-kernels through conda.

I tried to follow the advice given above and  already had Anaconda installed (via the windows installer) but when I tried:

```
conda update anaconda
```

It could not find Anaconda inside the base environment. So I installed Anaconda using conda anyway (even though this seems kind of recursive to me):

```
conda install anaconda
```

After that I was able to update Anaconda by:

```
conda update anaconda
```

Once I did that I was able to run Spyder 4 from the base environment (already installed) and I was getting a working Ipython kernel.

So then I could open Spyder from the base environment and using the Spyder menu, Tools -> Preferences -> Python Interpreter,  I can set the conda environment I want to be in, eg,
C:\Users<User Name>\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\python.exe

Then, to allow Spyder to create a Ipython Kernel inside the conda environment that I would like to work in,  I have to install spyder-kernels into this environment, so, I started up a new Anaconda prompt, and:

```
conda activate myenv

conda install spyder-kernels
```

Finally, back in Spyder, I restarted my kernel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>). This gave me a functioning Ipython kernel , and looking at the status bar at the bottom of the Spyder window, I could see that I was in the myenv environment.

So now I can use the Spyder IDE (starting it from the base environment) but be able to work inside previously created conda environments. It also avoids having to install the full Spyder into each environment I create (but does mean having to install spyder-kernels into each environment).

Comment: Tried to install spyder-kernels in my env but there are a lot of conflicts in the packages. Do you know how to proceed? In my env, Sypder does not install through conda install or in the Navigator itself. Thanks, @land-ahoy.

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't update Spyder to v4.0.0 on Win x64; but I found a solution.

A word about my setup: I use Miniconda and a conda environment with `conda-forge` as the top channel & the setting `channel_priority: strict` (a recommendation according to [conda-forge](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html#strict-channel-priority)). This causes conda to *only* consider packages from the conda-forge channel.

I disabled the strict channel priority for my active environment (which may be undesired in the future with conda v5.0+ [[conda-forge](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html#strict-channel-priority)]):

```
conda config --env --set channel_priority disabled
```

Now finally, I was able to update Spyder to v4.0.0:

```
conda update spyder
```

It appeared that conda needed the following packages (it took it from the `defaults`/`anaconda` channel):
`blas`-1.0, `jupyter_client`-5.3.4, `pluggy`-0.13.1, `python`-3.7.5, `scipy`-1.3.2.
`jedi` was downgraded (0.15.1-py37_0 --> 0.14.1-py37_0).

FYI: I also considered the other answers of:

- [Carlos Cordoba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59269003/3801913) - Problem: I have Miniconda, and do not want all the other packages associated with `anaconda`.
- [pyXelr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59294022/3801913) - I tried downgrading of `conda` - didn't solve the problem.

---

Btw: creating a new clean environment with only Spyder v4.0.0 (and its dependencies) also only works with the strict channel priority `disable`d (when using `conda-forge`), that is, this **doesn't work**:

```
conda create -n spyder -c conda-forge --strict-channel-priority spyder=4.0.0
```

It also **won't work** if you execute the following from an environment with `strict` `channel_priority`:

```
conda create -n spyder -c conda-forge spyder=4.0.0
```

(you need to `disable` the `channel_priority` first)

Comment: I followed your recommandation, but it did not work, how do you open Spyder ?

Comment: Do you have the `conda-forge` channel added? If not, it may help: `conda config --env --add channels conda-forge`; then try to update again. I open Spyder simply from Windows' Start Menu

Comment: I got this new issue : `ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::autopep8-1.4.4-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\brichard\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by uninstalling Spyder then installing by the specific version:

```
conda uninstall spyder
```

```
conda install spyder=4.1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue, which probably occurred by keeping too many packages in the same *root environment*. 
Firstly, try downgrading conda, as it was suggested in the recent [issue on the conda repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9367#issuecomment-560343340):

```
conda install -n root conda=4.6
```

Afterwards, give Spyder one more chance:

```
conda install spyder=4.0.0
```

If that did not work, I believe you can solve the problem as I did - through **creating a new environment** (for example using Anaconda Navigator) **and installing Spyder 4.0.0 directly from there**.

Answer (score 1):

I had freshly installed Anaconda on my PC. So doing just the following in Anaconda command prompt worked for me. Spyder, along with a lot of others, was updated to 4.0.0.

```
conda update anaconda
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying

```
conda install spyder=4.1.2
```

then I did the below, it worked!

```
conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true
conda install conda=4.6.14
```