# Kernal Error (13) "Failed to Start Kernal" in Anything Python via Anaconda - after attempted Spyder 4.0 Update

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Help ---- 
**Please note:** I have already attempted the suggested fixes to similar ErrNo13 [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58174067/kernel-error-errno-13-permission-denied-in-jupyter-notebook-windows-10).  The proposed solution there WILL NOT work here (I can not run anaconda as an admin forever).

**Background:**
- Win 10
- Anaconda 1.9.7
- Recent attempt to update Spyder to 4.0 (err'd out)
- Currently unable to start Python Jupyter or Spyder
- Kernal Error top-right of Jupyter panel.

> Error Text: Failed to start the kernal, Unhandled Error

**Full Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f: 
 File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\markk\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
    with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\markk\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-2637dfaf-4206-40e7-aeea-56de7b61b129.json'
```

Comment: Do you have the error message you received when trying to update Spyder? How did you run the Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: -1. No, I had other error messages when attempting to update Spyder - and it did not update.    2. I ran Jupyter from the Anaconda Navigator IDE.  Note: I have not opened Python for one month, and wonder if I may have moved files in my directory - which could have caused both the Spyder update errors + the Python Errno 13?

Comment: _I have not opened Python for one month, and wonder if I may have moved files in my directory - which could have caused both the Spyder update errors + the Python Errno 13?_ That depends on the files you moved. You could try this in a new environment, I guess.

Comment: I further attempted to run jupyter notebook from the Anaconda Prompt - no success.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a solution - but a workaround!

Comment: _That doesn't sound like a solution - but a workaround!_ The suggestion to try a new environment?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Spyder maintainers are not adequately prompting Anaconda users on their 4.0 update - and this will cause these errors.  Note to Self: Don't trust Spyder update messages!

> [Trouble Updating Spyder 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265097/trouble-updating-to-spyder-4-0-0)