# Why can't I use the libraries in Spyder 4?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I downloaded Anaconda, and launched Spyder 3.something. I created a program that included sympy in it and ran it with no problems. When I re-opened Spyder later, I got a pop-up saying that Spyder Version 4.0.1 was available. I then went to update it. Once updated I tried to run the same code and it gave me an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'. What do I need to do so that all the libraries in Anaconda are use-able again in Spyder. I'm pretty new to Python.

Note: I did not do any initial setup to have sympy, numpy, etc. in Spyder 3.something, they were automatically implemented. Thanks!

Comment: The IDE doesn't manage the libraries. Anaconda / Pip do

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849718/how-to-update-spyder-on-anaconda?rq=1

Comment: I think you should be able to launch Spyder from the specific environment you want.

Comment: activate the env in anaconda prompt and launch spyder from that env by running `spyder`...try that