# Anaconda won't update spyder 4

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I just installed Anaconda and haven't changed anything. When I start spyder3 it tells me spyder 4 is available. 
So I decided to update it.
I tried

```
conda update  --all

conda update conda

conda update spyder
```

.

It all gave no errors, but when I start spyder it's all fine. I know this should work because I already did this in the past. 
Every help very appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update spyder on anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849718/how-to-update-spyder-on-anaconda)

Answer (score 4):

**The following methods work for Anaconda Navigator 2.0.4 (Mac).**

Update Anaconda Navigator

Go on the Anaconda Navigator and click on the gear on the top right corner of the Spyder "icon".

Click Remove.

Wait a couple of minutes for it to remove.

Then click refresh (if doesn't refresh automatically).

Spyder should reappear and the latest version should be suggested for installation. **However**, click again on the gear, install version-specific, and select the desired version.

If it doesn't work, remove Spyder again, open Terminal, and enters:

```
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.0.5
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was clicking the "remove application" option in the settings in the top left corner of Spyder on the Anaconda Navigator. Once I removed it, it gave me an option to reinstall the newest version of Spyder.

You may have to do the commands above (for example, conda update --all) to "unlock" the newer versions after removal, though.

Comment: This worked for me as well, whereas other approaches described here did not.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem , i have an environment with Spyder 3.3.1 
when i try update from command line says it's already installed.
have tried
conda update -n $ENV_NAME spyder
conda update spyder

when i try and update it through anaconda navigator it says "all requested packages already installed" but it hasn't it still remains as version 3.3.1

Worked out that i had to upgrade to python 3.6 at least. but had a lot of trouble doing that with all the existing dependencies.

finally i just created a new environment with 3.7 and spyder 4.3, so not ideal but at least it works

Answer (score 2):

upgrading the spyder version from Anaconda Navigator worked for me.

1. Open the Anaconda Navigator
2. Go to the spyder tile
3. Click on the gear icon on the spyder tile
4. Choose from the option "Install specific version"

This should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem. - cannot upgrade to Spyder 4.0.1. I thought I'd provide some more details here. I've also just reformatted my disk and re-installed windows 10. Installed visual studio 2019 tools (if it matters). I just installed the latest Anaconda Distribution 2019.10 (windows x64)

I've run the following to no avail....

```
conda update conda
```

`conda update anaconda` (not sure if its any different)

Neither conda update method downloads spyder 4.0.1

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

This method downloads and re-installs spyder 3.3.6

```
conda install spyder=4.0.1
```

[this method errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogsa3.png)

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To update to Spyder 4 in Anaconda you need to

- Close Spyder.
- Open the Anaconda Prompt (Windows), Terminal.app (macOS) or xterm/konsole/gnome-terminal (Linux).
- Run the following commands:

  ```
  conda update anaconda
  conda install spyder=4
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Going through Anaconda Navigator worked for me. Not sure what command prompt didn't work. But I'm leaving my other 'answer' here in case anyone can speak to that issue.

Solution:

1. Open Anaconda Navigator
2. If prompted, update Anaconda Navigator
3. Click the settings tab on the Spyder card --> 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Run Anaconda as admin, click on the gear in the upper right corner of the Spyder app, click update. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what worked for me - all through the UI (The gear icon on the app tiles):**

1. Make sure your Anaconda is the latest version. Mine is 2.0.3
2. Remove Spyder
3. Install Spyder
4. After Spyder is installed, install the specific version (if it is NOT up to date already).

Answer (score -1):

I have performed the following command to upgrade spyder3 to spyder4

```
conda update --all
```

Os: Ubuntu 20.04
conda: base (python3.7.7)

Also the following commands did not help upgrade spyder3 to spyder4

```
conda update conda
conda update spyder
```

Please let us know if it works for you in windows OS.