# How to upgrade Spyder in Anaconda?

Tags: installation, anaconda, upgrade, spyder

I just installed new Anaconda with Python 3.7. The Spyder version is still 3.36 and it says there is an new version 4.0.1 available each time I started Spyder.

I tried to upgrade Spyder using two approach:

1. `conda update spyder` (it didn't work even there was no error)
2. `conda install spyder=4.0.1`

Using second method, found so many conflict like below.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update spyder on anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849718/how-to-update-spyder-on-anaconda)

Answer (score 0):

Open "Anaconda Navigator" and in Spyder Frame you'll see a gear icon, click on that and then click on "Update Application".

Comment: You're right. I'll try to make it better. @halfer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using the Spyder icon little wheel of Anaconda home. It was running forever and, if lucky stopped without updating.

To solve the issue, I opened the "Anaconda prompt" (as admin, just in case), launched the command:
    conda update --all
The back to Anaconda home, little wheel of Spyder icon and chose the highest version. The install tool a few dozen of secs.